# bringing in Wordpress post titles as links

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and I'm using the basic loop to bring in each Wordpress post

html

```
<?php 
 if ( have_posts() ) {
     while ( have_posts() ) {
     the_post(); 
     //
     // Post Content here
     //
    } // end while
  } // end if
?>
```

However I only want to bring in the title of each post as a link to that post (on its own single.php page) instead of all the content/images, etc. I have only been able to get all or nothing results.

Comment: Does "on its own single.php page" mean every post has like a custom template? If so, where do you set that value? I mean the problem is not only getting the link of the post instead of the content? Or is that the only problem you are facing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By keeping your code, you can go this way.

```
<?php 
 if ( have_posts() ) {
     while ( have_posts() ) {
     the_post(); 
     //
     echo '<h2><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
     //
    } // end while
  } // end if
?>
```

This way you'll get only your title with permalink. let me know if it helps you out or any thing else needed ?

Answer (score 0):

hi you can give something like this

```
<?php 
 if ( have_posts() ) {
 while ( have_posts() ) {
 the_post(); 
 //
 echo '<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>';
 //
  } // end while
 } // end if
?>
```

for further details you can refer this site
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink